# Zoom shows only whiteboard sharing option when I try to share sceen

Tags: zoom-meeting

This is really strange. After a recent upgrade, I am getting only the Whiteboard option. Please see the screenshots below.

[image]
[image]

If I remember correctly, I am supposed to get the options for the whole window and specific applications.

Please see my settings below. Nothing strange there, I believe.

[image]

**EDIT:**

More information,

1. Installable application.
2. Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

uncomment the line

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

to

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

Then reboot.

Comment: This isn't necessarily the ideal solution.

This change disables Wayland, but Zoom screen-sharing should work in Wayland sessions as well